# What's the benefit of using Visibility when the code inside it still works

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter recommends we shouldn't change widget tree depth for better performance.

**Code-1 (changes depth but stops method from getting called):**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text("Keep it visible"),
      if (_show) _buildAnotherWidget(), // it changes depth of the tree, not good, but my method doesn't get called
    ],
  );
}
```

**Code-2 (doesn't change depth and can't stop method from getting called):**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text("Keep it visible"),
      Visibility(
        visible: false,
        child: _buildAnotherWidget(), // recommended way but even my method keeps getting called
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

So why `Visibility` fails to stop calling the method when `visible` is set to `false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking why `_buildAnotherWidget()` is called with the `Visibility` widget case, it's because you're calling `_buildAnotherWidget()` *unconditionally*.  Arguments are evaluated *before* invoking the function/constructor; the `Visibility` widget has no control over that.  If you want `_buildAnotherWidget()` to be called lazily with that approach, you'd need to use a `Builder`.  That said, [the recommendation is to prefer omitting the widget from the tree instead of using `Visibility`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html).

Comment: Thank you so much James for giving the idea. I really appreciate the in-depth look you provided. BTW do you work for Google?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that `Visibility` does not change the depth of the tree is false.

By default, it does and is equivalent to:

```dart
if (visible)
  return child;
else
  return const SizedBox();
```

So this likely invalidate the question altogether.

Comment: Thanks a lot again for answering my question. Would you mind telling me what's the best possible way to prevent changing the depth and still hiding a widget?

Comment: Offstage, Opacity, or `Visibility` (with `maintainState: true`). But you shouldn't worry about that anyway.